# The Windows Phone Emulator requires Hyper-V

Tags: windows-phone-8

when i run a windows phone app program immediately a error message.

The Windows Phone Emulator requires Hyper-V. Your PC is missing the following pre-requisites required to run Hyper-V: Windows 8 .1 Professional (64-bit)

i already check those links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj863509%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2013/11/05/step-by-step-enabling-hyper-v-for-use-on-windows-8-1.aspx

I can't find the BIOS settings in my system as such images shown in the above link.

software configuration:

Windows Phone SDK 8.0

Visual studio 2013 Ulitimate

SYSTEM CONFIGURATION

os: windows 8.1

processor: intel(R) core(TM) i5-3210 CPU @2.50GHz 2.50GHz

RAM:6GP

SYSTEM TYPE: 64 BIT OPERATING SYSTEM,x64 BASED PROCESSOR

Hyper-V Requirements: VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: Yes
Second Level Address Translation: Yes
Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes

Answer (score 2):

Are you running Windows 8.1 Professional (64-bit) ? Seems like that is what it's complaining about.

EDIT: Yes, according to the docs here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626524(v=vs.105).aspx you need to be running a Pro version of Windows 8.

This taken from the link above **64-bit version of Windows 8 Pro edition or higher.**

Answer (score 2):

1)Turn on Visualization in your BIOS settings.

2) make sure you've turned on Hyper-V on windows
[Run -> type in "optionalfeatures" -> select Hyper-V from list (Restart Mandatory)]

3) use [Microsoft Coreinfo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/cc835722.aspx) tool to verify compatibly 
[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/cc835722.aspx]