# Windows Phone 8.1 Emulator isn't starting on Windows 8.1 (64-bit)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, emulation, windows-phone-8.1

I have trouble with WP 8.1 Emulator. I run it from Visual Studio 2013 Update 2, but I get error message: *Your computer is missing the following pre-requistes required to run Hyper-V:

 - Windows 8 Professional (64-bit)*. 
I don't have Pro version of my OS but both **systeminfo** command and **coreinfo** program show my PC is ready for Hyper-V:
coreinfo:

```
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3632QM CPU @ 2.20GHz
Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
HYPERVISOR  -   Hypervisor is present
VMX         *   Supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization
EPT         *   Supports Intel extended page tables (SLAT)
```

systeminfo:

```
Hyper-V Requirements:  VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
                       Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: Yes
                       Second Level Address Translation: Yes
                       Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The Windows Phone Emulator requires Hyper-V](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21756229/the-windows-phone-emulator-requires-hyper-v)

Comment: As far as I know this is a programing board, not a phone troubleshooting one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything fine on your system but you have to install windows-8 pro or above to run windows phone emulator on your computer. You can check minimum requirement on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks, I supposed so but I wasn't sure. I've got just one more question. Is it possible to change my OS to Pro version without reinstalling it? I have many programs and drivers installed (including these ones installed by Lenovo) and I'd like to avoid looking for it and installing once again.

Comment: I don't have any idea about it.

Comment: @user3855877 Yes, you can upgrade your Windows 8 Os to Windows 8 Pro Os without re installing but you have to pay for it.

Comment: Yes, I got it. There's Windows Anytime Upgrade service. Fortunately I have access to MS DreamSpark licence.