# Unable to start Windows Phone Emulator

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I was facing this problem before and wrote on msdn and was urged to uninstall all the components and I did that.
Again installed Visual Studio Community 2013 and I am facing this problem.

Windows Phone Emulator requires Hyper-V. Your computer is missing the following pre-requisites requied to run Hyper-V:

- Windows 8 Professional (64-bit)

I am using hp Envy m6 with AMD processor and 6GB RAM (Factory installed Windows 8.1 Professinal). I believe my PC meets the requirements specified by Microsoft. And I have enabled virtualization in the BIOS settings.

PS. Thank you stackoverflow for not allowing me post a snapshot of the problem!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21756229/the-windows-phone-emulator-requires-hyper-v and you can well post the snapshot..

Comment: @PrasannaAarthi I'd be so much grateful if could post the screenshot. And that will explain my problem very well. I am not allowed to. I need some reputation thing on this website.

Comment: Post your snapshot in some other server and give the URL here..