# Start Windows Phone 8.1 emulator in win 10

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8

Is it possible?

When I try to run windows phone 8.1 app in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate I get :

> This computer does not support the Windows Phone emulator, which
>   requires the 64-bit edition of Windows 8.1 Pro and a computer that
>   supports Hyper-V

I have Hyper-V run&ready and win 10 64 bit, is there a any way to run WP emulator without creating VM with win 8.1?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32293072/50447

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21756229/50447

Comment: And... http://stackoverflow.com/q/25089523/50447